# Primereact Datatable: Data undefined on editorCallback when focusing multiple InputTexts

Tags: javascript, typescript, primereact

I am using Datatable from Primereact and followed the documentation on implementing Cell Editing.

```
const textEditor = (options: any) => {
  return (
    <InputText
      className="text-xs w-full"
      value={options.value}
      onChange={(e) => {
        console.log(options);
        options.editorCallback(e.target.value);
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Inside the InputText component's onChange function, *options.editorCallback(e.target.value)* is causing an error saying that "*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')*"

Upon inspection using the browser devtool, there is a value inside *data* in editorCallback() function when I edit the InputText the first time.

```
var editorCallback = function editorCallback(val) {
  var editingRowData = _objectSpread$7({}, editingRowDataState);

  editingRowData[field] = val;
  setEditingRowDataState(editingRowData);

  props.editingMeta[editingKey].data[field] = val;
};
```

But when I change focus multiple times and then edit an InputText, the *data* becomes undefined hence causing the issue.

[Here is a screenshot of the callback with value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOHuU.png)

[Here is a screenshot of the callback with no values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1X3X.png)

Does anyone know the problem and how to fix it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue when adding a new row to the table and then programmatically adding that row's id to the `DataTable` `editingRows` property. Then when I would try to pick an option from a `DropDown`, some editing states had not been initialized and this error would be trown.

For some reason this only happens in the production build or when you comment out the `<React.StrictMode>` lines in the `index.jsx` file, which means that only happens when strict mode is disabled. I guess the extra renders caused by `<React.StrictMode>` are masking the issue.

What worked for me was to add a new row without adding it to the `editingRows` object. And force the user to click the pencil icon to edit it. This will initialize some needed states in the `DataTable` and prevent that error from happening.

I also added some logic to pick some options using the `onRowEditInit` event so that the row does not initialize with the empty `DropDown` inputs.

I recommend you open an issue in the PrimeReact repository, if you have not yet.